# How Magento 2 loads and manipulates configuration information?

Tags: magento2, configuration, xml, core

In Magento 1.X We know how the configuration is loading.

If we trace the code performance starting from index.php, we’ll get the following key points ( The exact order may be differ ).

For example

```
Index.php
Mage::run()
self::$_app    = new Mage_Core_Model_App();
self::$_app->run(…);
Mage::app()
self::$_app-> init (…);

// Initialization of core configuration
$this->loadBase();
$this->loadModules();
$this->loadDb();
$this->saveCache();
$this->_loadDeclaredModules();
$this->loadModulesConfiguration(array('config.xml',$resourceConfig), $this);
```

**How does Magento2 operate all these files and find proper settings for each particular extension ?**

Clear answer will help more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Magento 2, there are three steps in loading configuration files:

1. **System-level files**: these are files required for the application to start and installation-specific configuration for example `app/etc/config.php`
2. **Global files**: the global `app/etc/di.xml` is loaded first, followed by the `di.xml` file from every module along with other module configuration files (like `event.xml`)
3. **Area-specific files**: these are configuration files for other specific areas such as adminhtml and the frontend like `routes.xml`

Some config files can be loaded at more than one stage -- for example, `di.xml` can be loaded at any of the stages; `config.xml` can be loaded as a primary or global file.

All Magento 2 config files are processed by the libray component `Magento\Config`. **This component loads, merges and validates XML configuration files against schemas in XSD format, and then converts them to proper array format.**

Regarding the workflow, here's a diagram that'll help you understand it:

[image]

In the left column of the diagram, all the steps displayed are always performed – a request is sent to the `index.php`, which initiates the
bootstrap. The bootstrap then initiates the `App` class - in our case, `Magento\Framework\App\Http`, into which Magento loads
configuration.

Comment: @ Raphael Thanks , Can you please explain the workflow a bit deeper. like i mentioned.

Comment: @krishnaijjada I've added a picture to help you understand the workflow

Comment: @ Raphael Helpful + 1.